# Please help me understand unexpected output from the command, `octez-dac-node config show`

Tags: smart-rollup

The output from the command `octez-dac-node --base-dir "$client-dir" config show` reads:

> Warning: no config file at /home/phil/.tezos-client/config, displaying
> the default configuration.  { "base_dir": "/home/phil/.tezos-client",
> "endpoint": "http://localhost:20000", "web_port": 8080,
> "confirmations": 0 }

This is unexpected because the dac-node config is located at
`/home/phil/.tezos-dac-node/config.json` and contains:

> { "data-dir": "/home/phil/.tezos-dac-node", "rpc-port": 22222 }

Why does the  output state that there is no config at the `$client-dir`? Is `config show` meant to show the dac-node config, or some other config? (I am running the octez-dac-node in a sandbox running protoalpha).

Comment: It looks like your paths don't match: `/home/phil/.tezos-client/config` vs `/home/phil/.tezos-dac-node/config.json`. Perhaps `client_dir` isn't set properly?

Comment: That is why I'm confused. The second directory above is the one that I set and is where the config file can be found. Also, note that the rpc-ports don't match. Again the second one is the one that I set with the `init-config` command.